re upload same texture into the object make the object texture different and low quality
i tried to update the texture on my glb file with some texture images and same texture image, but it was always like has some striped on my texture after update map texture
here is my current texture look up before update

here is my current texture look up after update with the same texture

this is how i i update the texture:

inputTexture.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
    const textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    textureLoader.load(getFile(event), (newTexture) => {
        canvasEl.style.display = 'block'

        // newTexture.encoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
        // newTexture.flipY = false;

        // Update the model's material with the new texture
        model.traverse((node) => {
            if (node.isMesh) {
                node.material.map = newTexture
                node.material.needsUpdate = true;
                node.material.map.needsUpdate = true; // Ensure material update
            }
        });
    }, (xhr) => {
        canvasEl.style.display = 'none'
        loading.innerHTML = Math.floor((xhr.loaded / xhr.total) * 100) + '% loaded'
    }, (err) => {
        loading.innerHTML = 'failed load hdr, refresh page ' + JSON.stringify(err)
    });
});


is that any i miss here? i did change the flipY to false also, but it doesn't work
i do love after i update same texture it suppose to be same like before , because when i upload other textures, it was same not like expected, and it has some striped on the texture and blurry
